# IBM DL Experiments Error - "Failed: store_results_exit_code: 0, 0: 0"

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to use the IBM Watson platform to make training runs and check different experiments. I wanted to initialize it at first, but I receive the error message
`Failed: store_results_exit_code: 0, 0: 0`

The input data I am using is a pickle file with format (X, y) with a numpy array of image data for X, and one-hot encoded labels for y. I use 6 categories and an image size of `224x224`. The data is uploaded to the IBM Cloud storage and linked to the training definition. That training definition was created in the neural network modeler. I have defined a simple 5-layer network with 3 Convolution-layers and 2 Dense-layers. 
When I start the training, it gets interrupted after about a minute. The console shows the error mentioned above.
In case you need further information, please let me know, so I can provide that.